# Header width is smaller than longtable width

Tags: header-footer, longtable

I have been trying to create a longtable using a csv. But I can't find out why the header width is smaller than the table width. The data is the following:

```
Nombre,Frec,Prop
Eixample,3106,0.2640
Sant Marti,1399,0.1189
Sarria-Sant Gervasi,1354,0.1151
Sants-Montjuic,1199,0.1019
Horta-Guinardo,1054,0.0896
Sant Andreu,903,0.0767
Les Corts,881,0.0749
Nou Barris,735,0.0625
Gracia,625,0.0531
Ciutat Vella,511,0.0434
```

My code is:

```
\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\caption {Tabla de frecuencias de Distrito}
\hline
\textbf{Distrito} & \textbf{Frec} & \textbf{Prop}
\\ \hline 
\endhead
\csvreader[
    late after line= \\,
    late after last line=\\\hline %
]
{Tablas/Distrito.csv}
{Nombre=\Nombre,Frec=\Frec,Prop=\Prop}%
{\Nombre & \Frec & \Prop}
\end{longtable}
```

The following table is shown:

[image]

I'm using longtable because there are other tables that are long enough. All of them have the same problem. Any idea how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: you have not provided a usable example, but have you run the document enough times for longtable widths to stabilize?

Comment: can you really use \csvreader in the middle of a longtable? I'm surprised.

Comment: Yeah It can be done. I'm trying to solve all the other errors or warnings. Maybe is due to some other error.

Comment: You need `\\\` at the end of the caption line. Then I get the headers perfectly aligned.

Comment: I have tried what you say in a separate test document and it works! However, there is some other issue that will not leave the widths as they should be. I will solve the other warnings and errors in order to solve this problem. Once I find the errror, I will notify it. Thank you.

Comment: I added "\\" to all the other longtables and now everything works fine. Thank you David and Pieter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding **\\** after the caption code line. The final code would be:

```
\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\caption {Tabla de frecuencias de Distrito} \\
\hline
\textbf{Distrito} & \textbf{Frec} & \textbf{Prop}
\\ \hline 
\endhead
\csvreader[
    late after line= \\,
    late after last line=\\\hline %
]
{Tablas/Distrito.csv}
{Nombre=\Nombre,Frec=\Frec,Prop=\Prop}%
{\Nombre & \Frec & \Prop}
\end{longtable}
```

If it still does not work, you should add it to all the other longtable that you have and it should work.